# Pythonのシリアル通信をリアルタイムで監視できるようにするには

Tags: python, シリアル通信

ESP32に繋いだマイクからの値をシリアル通信でpythonに流し、その流れてきた値をリアルタイムでmatplotlibのグラフにプロットするプログラムを作成しようとしています。
以下がそのコードです。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-0001', 230400)

fig = plt.figure()


x_max = 1024
x_array = [x_max]

while len(x_array) != x_max:
    x_array.append(float(ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()))

def plot(data):
    plt.cla()                      # 現在描写されているグラフを消去
    addValue = float(ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip())
    print(time.time())
    print(addValue)
    x_array[:-1] = x_array[1:]
    x_array[-1] = addValue
    rand = x_array
    plt.plot(rand)            # グラフを生成

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plot, interval=1)
plt.show()
ser.close()
```

これを実行してもリアルタイムで値が変わりません。というのもマイク付近で音を立てても値が変わらないのです。
しかしながら

```
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import time

# シリアルポートの設定（ポート名は適宜変更してください）
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-0001', 230400)

while True:
    print(float(ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()))
    print(time.time())

ser.close()
```

このコードを実行してターミナルを監視していると騒音を立てたときはちゃんと値が大きくぶれます。

先のコードではどうして音を立てても値がぶれないのでしょうか？

初心者で恐縮ですが有識者の方、ご意見をよろしくお願いいたします。

-追記-
皆様、回答ありがとうございます。 やはりリアルタイムでプロットすることができません。 arduino側のシリアル通信送信間隔, matplotlibのFuncAnimationのインターバルともに0.001秒にしているので間隔に差もないと思うのですがこの考え方が間違っているのでしょうか？ 例えば、何もしていないとき1900あたりの値を拾っていてマイクに触ったり息を吹くと4000くらいまで上がる予想です。（arduinoIDEのシリアルプロットではそうなります）しかしながらpythonで上記のコードを書いても4000まで上がらず何も変わりません汗 このことも踏まえてどなたかわかる方いらっしゃったらコメントお願い致します。

Comment: この辺の記事が類似の内容を扱っていると思われるので参考にしてみてはどうでしょう？ [シリアルポートからくるデータをリアルタイムにプロットする](https://qiita.com/aerialist/items/ad2cfa95ca5a195f1e09), [pythonでシリアルプロッタ](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/lm324/e/256b8f14f8c99ec24074d9e0ea02f721), [ArduinoとPythonとmatplotlibを用いたリアルタイムデータモニタリング(real-time data monitoring)](https://poissondd.wordpress.com/2015/05/26/arduino%E3%81%A8python%E3%81%A8matplotlib%E3%82%92%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A0%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AA/)

Comment: データを送信する側と受信する側の実行される間隔とデータの取り方の問題かもしれませんね。データを送信するESP32側のプログラムを変更して、受信する側と同様に1ミリ秒毎に1個のデータを送信するようにしてみてはどうでしょう？ あと1ミリ秒毎にplotが呼ばれてクリア・読み取り・再描画を行っているように見えますが、それで処理が出来ているのでしょうか？ 出来ているとしても人間の目で追えてスムーズに描画しているように見えるものでしょうか？ デフォルトだと200ミリ秒毎になっているようですが。[\[Python/matplotlib\] FuncAnimationを理解して使う](https://qiita.com/osanshouo/items/3c66781f41884694838b), [【Matplotlib】FuncAnimationクラスを使用してグラフ内にアニメーションを描画する](https://zerofromlight.com/blogs/detail/101/), [Python – FuncAnimationによる動画表示](http://taustation.com/python-funcanimation-graph-animation/)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
後々FFTを使いたいのでできるだけ送受信間隔を短くしたいと考えています。そのほうが高周波までFFTできるため。なので1ミリ秒で更新をしている次第です。ちなみにグラフ描写が重くて間に合っていないだけかとも考えましたがグラフ描写ではなくprint()を使ってもリアルタイムにはなりませんでした汗

Comment: 送信側でもログを採取あるいは表示して受信側と照合してみるとかどうでしょう？

Answer (score 1):

※ 以下は回答ではなく、シリアル通信をエミュレートして、質問にあるプログラム・コードの動作確認を行ったものです

`Python 3.11.6`, `matplotlib 3.8.2` を使用しています。また、シリアル通信をエミュレートするために `fakeSerial` パッケージを利用しています。(`[0, 10]` の乱数を返します)
質問のコードを意味的に改変した箇所はなく、元のコードのままでも問題なく描画できている様に見えます。

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
# import serial
import fakeSerial as serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-0001', 230400)

fig = plt.figure()
x_max = 1024
x_array = []

while len(x_array) < x_max:
    x_array.append(float(ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()))

def plot(data):
    plt.cla()                    # 現在描写されているグラフを消去
    addValue = float(ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip())
    x_array.pop(0)
    x_array.append(addValue)
    plt.plot(x_array)            # グラフを生成

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plot, interval=1, frames=100)
plt.show()
# ani.save('serial.gif', writer='imagemagick')
ser.close()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 皆様、回答ありがとうございます。
やはりリアルタイムでプロットすることができません。
arduino側のシリアル通信送信間隔, matplotlibのFuncAnimationのインターバルともに0.001秒にしているので間隔に差もないと思うのですがこの考え方が間違っているのでしょうか？
例えば、何もしていないとき1900あたりの値を拾っていてマイクに触ったり息を吹くと4000くらいまで上がる予想です。（arduinoIDEのシリアルプロットではそうなります）しかしながらpythonで上記のコードを書いても4000まで上がらず何も変わりません汗
このことも踏まえてどなたかわかる方いらっしゃったらコメントお願い致します。

Comment: @RioPin1002 私の回答にコメントするだけですと、気が付くには私だけになってしまします。なので、そのコメントは質問に追記するとよいかと思います。(質問内容が更新されると表示順位が先頭になって他の回答者の人たちも気が付くことになります)

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

手元の環境で適当なセンサーとシリアル通信をして動かしたところ、他の回答と同様にご質問のコードが問題なく動作しました。

考えられる原因として、初期化時点でY軸の幅が大きくなっているにもかかわらずシリアル通信で取得できる値が小数点以下の小さい値だったりしないでしょうか？
以下のサンプルでは`while`文の初期化処理で大きな値を与えることで、その後のセンサーが戻す1未満の値を視認できないようにしています。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
#import serial
import time

#ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-0001', 230400)

# 0から1未満まで値の変更を繰り返すダミーのシリアル値を返すモッククラス
class MySerial:
    def readline(self):
        t = time.time()
        return str(t - int(t)).encode('utf-8') #小数点以下のみ取得

ser = MySerial()
fig = plt.figure()
x_max = 1024
x_array = [x_max]

while len(x_array) != x_max:
    #x_array.append(float(ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()))
    x_array.append(10000) # 大きな値を最初に補完すると最初のグラフの変化が見えなくなる

def plot(data):
    plt.cla()                      # 現在描写されているグラフを消去
    addValue = float(ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip())
    x_array[:-1] = x_array[1:]
    x_array[-1] = addValue
    rand = x_array
    plt.plot(rand)            # グラフを生成

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plot, interval=1)
plt.show()
#ser.close()
```

[image: グラフ]

Answer (score -1):

コード自体がリアルタイムで値を出すようになっていません。

最初のwhileループはなにもしないようになっていますが、これは想定している動作なんでしょうか

Comment: おそらく最初のwhileループはグラフを表示する前にデータが1024個になるようにあらかじめ初期値の1024およびデバイスからの1023個のデータを読んで格納しておく処理でしょう。